# Can't use Alamofire after importing Cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

My podfile looks like the following

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RedPepper
  pod 'Alamofire'

end
```

I then import Alamofire, and when I try to use, the only Alamofire property available to me is `AlamofireVersionNumber` (Double)

I am in the workspace, I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, redoing cocoapods. I'm kinda of lost at this point.

Comment: type this-->Alamofire.request

Comment: put use_frameworks! outside target 'MyProject' do

Comment: Why is there no autocomplete on Alamofire? Never had this problem before with cocoapods

Comment: probably you use the last version of Alamofire but your swift version is not same or higher than that